# HDIV : I'm getting a NullPointerException when accessing a page

Tags: java, html, tags, struts-1, hdiv

I'm in the last step before releasing the new version of an application which is using HDIV security framework.

currently I'm getting NullPointerException when accessing this application through the login page. The weird thing is that I never had this kind of exception with the same page before. But I already had this kind of exception with another page yesterday.

Any idea why I'm getting this random exception ?

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.hdiv.taglib.html.TextTagHDIV.doStartTag(TextTagHDIV.java:52)
            at org.hdiv.strutsel.taglib.html.ELTextTagHDIV.doStartTag(ELTextTagHDIV.java:926)
            at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005ftext_005f0(login_jsp.java:421)
            at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:345)
            at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fhtml_005f0(login_jsp.java:229)
            at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:119)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
            at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsForward(PerformForward.java:113)
            at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:96)
            at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
            at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
            at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
            at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
            at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
            at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
            at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
            at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            ...
            Unhandled exception [org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExceptionHandler] [execute() 95]
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 41

    38:                     
    39:                     <tr>
    40:                         <td align="left"><fmt:message key="login.userName" /></td>
    41:                         <td><label> <html:text property="userName"
    42:                             styleClass="baTextField" styleId="login" /> 
    43:                             </label></td>
    44:                     </tr>


    Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsForward(PerformForward.java:113)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:96)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I found it it was because I put <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern> for the validator filter. With the pattern <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> I don’t get the NullPointerException. So How to tell HDIV to protect only the administration part of the application ?

Comment: Follow same issue in GitHub: https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/issues/88